# Evaluate $\int_{0}^\infty\frac{2}{({M-1})!}\sqrt{\frac{a}{x}}K_1\left(2\sqrt{\frac{a}{x}}\right)x^{M-1}\frac{e^{-\frac{x}{b}}}{b^M}\,dx$

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals, special-functions

How to evaluate this integral or at least rewrite it as special (non-elementary) function step by step ?
$$\int_{0}^\infty\frac{2}{({M-1})!}\sqrt{\frac{a}{x}}K_1\left(2\sqrt{\frac{a}{x}}\right)x^{M-1}\frac{e^{-\frac{x}{b}}}{b^M}\,dx$$
Where $M$ is a positive integer that is $M=1,2,3,4,...$ , $a,b$ are two positive number and ${K_1}\left( . \right)$ is the modified Bessel function of order 1.

If you could provide some reference, I would be pretty much graceful !

Thank you for your enthusiasm !

Comment: There are some related integrals [here](https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.43) but I am altogether skeptical as to whether this has a closed form (or even converges).

Comment: Looks like:$\frac{G_{0,3}^{3,0}\left(\frac{a}{b}|
\begin{array}{c}
 0,1,M \\
\end{array}
\right)}{(M-1)!}$ by CAS.

Comment: Oh but is there anyway to show that explicitly ? or at least some references from the dlmf

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems useful to rearrange the integral:
\begin{align}
 I&=\int_{0}^\infty\frac{2}{({M-1})!}\sqrt{\frac{a}{x}}K_1\left(2\sqrt{\frac{a}{x}}\right)x^{M-1}\frac{e^{-\frac{x}{b}}}{b^M}\,dx\\
 &=\frac{2b^{-M}\sqrt{a}}{({M-1})!}\int_{0}^\infty K_1\left(2\sqrt{\frac{a}{x}}\right)x^{M-3/2}e^{-\frac{x}{b}}\,dx\\
 &=\frac{2}{({M-1})!}\left( \frac{a}{b} \right)^M\int_{0}^\infty K_1\left(\frac{2}{\sqrt s}\right)s^{M-3/2}e^{-\frac{a}{b}s}\,ds
\end{align}
which expresses that the integral is a function of $a/b$.

To obtain the Meijer function expression given by @MariuszIwaniuk in the comment, one may use the [Mellin-Barnes representation](https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.32.E13) for the modified Bessel function
\begin{equation}
 K_{\nu}\left(z\right)=\frac{(\frac{1}{2}z)^{\nu}}{4\pi i}\int_{c-i\infty}^{c+i\infty}\Gamma\left(t\right)\Gamma\left(t-\nu\right)(\tfrac{1}{2}z)^{-2t}\,dt
\end{equation}
valid for $c>\max⁡(\Re⁡\nu,0),|\arg⁡ z|<\pi/2$. Here, with $\nu=1,z=2/\sqrt s,c>1$, we obtain, by changing the order of integration
\begin{align}
 I&=\frac{2}{({M-1})!}\left( \frac{a}{b} \right)^M\int_{0}^\infty K_1\left(\frac{2}{\sqrt s}\right)s^{M-3/2}e^{-\frac{a}{b}s}\,ds\\
 &=\frac{1}{({M-1})!}\left( \frac{a}{b} \right)^M\frac{1}{2\pi i}
 \int_{c-i\infty}^{c+i\infty}\Gamma\left(t\right)\Gamma\left(t-1\right)\,dt\int_{0}^\infty s^{t+M-2}e^{-\frac{a}{b}s}\,ds
\end{align}
The integral over $s$ gives directly a Gamma function,
\begin{equation}
 I=\frac{1}{({M-1})!}\left( \frac{a}{b} \right)\frac{1}{2\pi i}
 \int_{c-i\infty}^{c+i\infty}\Gamma\left(t\right)\Gamma\left(t-1\right)\Gamma(t+M-1)\left(\frac ba\right)^t\,dt
\end{equation}
From the definition of the [Meijer function](https://dlmf.nist.gov/16.17.E1)
\begin{equation}
{G^{m,n}_{p,q}}\left(z;\begin{array}{c}
a_1,\ldots,a_p\\
b_1,\ldots,b_q
\end{array} \right)=\frac{1}{2\pi\mathrm{i}}\int_{L%
}{\frac{\prod\limits_{\ell=1}^{m}\Gamma\left(b_{\ell}-t\right
)\prod\limits_{\ell=1}^{n}\Gamma\left(1-a_{\ell}+t\right)}{\left(\prod\limits_%
{\ell=m}^{q-1}\Gamma\left(1-b_{\ell+1}+t\right)\prod\limits_{\ell=n}^{p-1}%
\Gamma\left(a_{\ell+1}-t\right)\right)}}z^{t}\,dt
\end{equation}
we can use $z=b/a$, $a_1=1,a_2=2,a_3=2-M$, with $m=q=0, n=p=3$ and an integral along the vertical axis from $c-i\infty$ to $c+i\infty$, as the real parts of the the poles of $\Gamma\left(1-a_{\ell}+t\right)$ are all less than $1$. We deduce
\begin{equation}
 I=\frac{1}{({M-1})!}\left( \frac{a}{b} \right)G^{0,3}_{3,0}\left(\frac{b}{a};\begin{array}{c}
1,2,2-M\\
\textrm{---}
\end{array} \right)
\end{equation}
The proposed expression can be retrieved by combining the [identity](https://dlmf.nist.gov/16.19.E1)
\begin{equation}
 I=\frac{1}{({M-1})!}\left( \frac{a}{b} \right)G^{3,0}_{0,3}\left(\frac{a}{b};\begin{array}{c}
 \textrm{---}\\
0,-1,M-1
\end{array} \right)
\end{equation}
and the second [identity](https://dlmf.nist.gov/16.19.E2)
\begin{equation}
 I=\frac{1}{({M-1})!}G^{3,0}_{0,3}\left(\frac{a}{b};\begin{array}{c}
 \textrm{---}\\
0,1,M
\end{array} \right)
\end{equation}

Comment: There seems to be an extraneous `d` in the Mellin-Barnes representation of $K_\nu$.

Comment: @NickD Thank you for pointing the typo!

Comment: Note:
$$
F(a/b) = \int_{0}^\infty K_1\left(\frac{2}{\sqrt s}\right)s^{M-3/2}e^{-\frac{a}{b}s}\,ds
$$
is the Laplace transform of
$$
f(s) = K_1\left(\frac{2}{\sqrt s}\right)s^{M-3/2}
$$
Can we find a table of Laplace transforms that includes expressions with Bessel functions in it?

Comment: I could not find it in Ederlyi.

Comment: Thank you very much @Paul Enta, when we come to this step 
$I = \frac{1}{{(M - 1)!}}{\left( {\frac{a}{b}} \right)^M}\frac{1}{{2\pi i}}\int_{c - i\infty }^{c + i\infty } \Gamma  \left( t \right)\Gamma \left( {t - 1} \right){\mkern 1mu} dt\int_0^\infty  {{s^{t + M - 2}}} {e^{ - \frac{a}{b}s}}{\mkern 1mu} ds$ the order of integration is $s$ first and $t$ second right ?

Comment: @TuongNguyenMinh My pleasure. Yes, the integral over $s$ gives a (Gamma) function of $t$ which is then integrated.

Comment: @PaulEnta the integration $\int\limits_{s = 0}^\infty  {{s^{t + M - 2}}{e^{ - \frac{a}{b}s}}} ds = \Gamma \left( {M + t - 1} \right){\left( {\frac{b}{a}} \right)^{M + t - 1}}$ but it seems that the power of $t$ has missing from $\left( {\frac{b}{a}} \right)$  ?
Particularly at this line 

$\begin{equation}
 I=\frac{1}{({M-1})!}\left( \frac{a}{b} \right)\frac{1}{2\pi i}
 \int_{c-i\infty}^{c+i\infty}\Gamma\left(t\right)\Gamma\left(t-1\right)\Gamma(t+M-1)\,dt
\end{equation}$

Comment: You are right, a factor was missing in the expression. Sorry for the typo which is corrected now.